# how to get index list in arrayList filter

Tags: filter, kotlin

I want to get index list as follows.

```
val a = booleanArrayOf(true,false,true,false)
```

above code, True number is two. -> indexList = {0, 2}
how to get indexList in Kotlin.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use `mapIndexed()` to get the index and the value of each element, convert to either the index or null, and then remove the nulls...

```
val b: List<Int> = a.mapIndexed { i, b -> if (b) i else null }.filterNotNull().toList()
```

Another way would be to use the `withIndex()` function, filter the values that are true, and map the resulting pairs to the index value. This might be a bit clearer.

```
val c: List<Int> = a.withIndex().filter { it.value }.map { it.index }
```

Comment: Thanks @Todd, I am using as below example
`val indexList: List<Int> = yourList.withIndex().filter {
                (!it.value.your_custom_object!!.keyName.equals("") && it.value.your_custom_object!!.keyName!!.equals(
                    "some_value", ignoreCase = true
                ))
            }.map { it.index }`